# How to mimic css multiple class names in jsx

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

How could I recreate the following css in a react style css module?

.thing1, .thing2, .thing3, .thing4 { color: red }

.thing5, .thing6, .thing7 { color: blue }

Essentially I receive a prop containing a number/string which are grouped to the same css. But im not sure how I would recreate this setup in javascript. The below seems a bit silly to have to do. I would also like If i could avoid doing something like a array look up

```
const styles = {
  thing1:{ color:red },
  thing2:{ color:red },
  thing3:{ color:red },
  thing4:{ color:red },
  thing5:{ color:blue },
  thing6:{ color:blue },
  thing7:{ color:blue },
}
```

Thoughts?

**Edit**

So an example would be:

```
render() {
  let {classes} = this.props
  return (
    <div className={??? + this.props.input}></div>
  )
}
```

if going the css route I would do

```
render() {
  let {classes} = this.props
  return (
    <div className={"thing" + this.props.input}></div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Could you show the full code here?

Answer (score 0):

I made a helper to merge the styles, here is it:

```
const mergeStyles = styles => styles.join(' ');    
export default mergeStyles;
```

And i use it this way:

```
<div className={mergeStyles([styles.boxInfo, styles.narrowBoxInfo])}>
```

If the styles are

```
.boxInfo {}
.narrowBoxInfo {}
```

Hope it helps!